# ASPX page has duplicate row(s) even though they are not duplicated in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listview, duplicates

**Problem**: One of the rows from SQL is getting duplicated onto the webpage anytime they have the same "Plan"

I've tried checking the Where and OrderBy of the statement to see if that is affecting why there are duplicates. I'm not sure why OrderBy would create duplicates though. I've tried this with multiple users and the behavior is consistent when they have the same Plan.

Example is below:

[image: SQL vs ASPX Page]
[image: More Examples]

Code(.cs):

```
var someVariable = DbContext.DbSet<>.Where(
                    m =>
                        m.Some_ID == CurrentlyEditingSomeID
                    ).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.Start_Date);
```

This references a ListView in the .aspx page, which has items such as the following:

```
   <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.Plan %></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.Start_Date.ToSafeShortDate() %></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.End_Date.ToSafeShortDate() %></td>
```

---

OUTPUT from the LINQ QUERY:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
[Project1].[Field2] AS [Field2], 

FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
    [Extent1].[Field2] AS [Field2], 

    FROM (SELECT 
[VIEW].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
[VIEW].[Field2] AS [Field2], 

FROM [mWeb].[VIEW] AS [VIEW]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Some_ID] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Start_Date] DESC
```

---

(longer version of .aspx file):

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstPlanE" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="litPlanEPlaceHolder"
        ItemType="Project.Data.view" SelectMethod="lstPlanE_GetData">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Nothing found</div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">G</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">G ID</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">Plan</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">Start Date</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">End Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litPlanEPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </table>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.G_Description %></td>

                       <% if (isAAA()) %> 
                       <% {  %>   
                                     <td><%# Item.AAA_G_ID %></td> 
                       <% } %>

                       <% else %>
                       <% { %>
                                 <td><%# Item.G_ID %></td>
                       <% } %>



                    <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.Plan %></td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.Start_Date.ToSafeShortDate() %></td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.End_Date.ToSafeShortDate() %></td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

---

(longer version of method in .cs file):

```
public IQueryable<MediView.Data.vx_EligibilitySearch> lstPlanE_GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (isAAA())
                {
                    var someVariable = DbContext.DbSet<>.Where(
                        m =>
                            m.Other_ID == CurrentlyEditingOtherID &&
                            m.Some_Seq == CurrentlyEditingSomeSeqID
                        ).AsQueryable();
                    return someVariable;
                }
                else
                {

                    var someVariable = DbContext.DbSet<>.Where(
                    m =>
                        m.Some_ID == CurrentlyEditingSomeID
                    ).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.Start_Date); 

                    return someVariable;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

---

```
public bool isAAA() // Determines if Site is CCC or Other
    {
        bool isSiteCCC = false;
        String browserTab = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowserTab.Trim(); // Gets Site Name from Settings file

        if (browserTab.Equals("Some Site Name")) { isSiteCCC = true; }

        return isSiteAAA;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are reassigning the `Item` object instead of having it in a loop? By the looks of your second SQL row, that might be the case. If you post more code perhaps it will be clear.

Comment: I updated code and the output. Maybe it will shed some light.

Comment: Your linq call looks fine to me, so it should be returning all items correctly. This would make me agree with Kristoffer. I would presume you aren't looping through the returned list and are instead showing the last item twice. Again if you can show more code it would give us a better idea.

Comment: Happy to provide more code, what would be most helpful?

Comment: Moved comment to potential answer to put code

Comment: Realised mistake in my answer. Could we see your isAAA method for a start then can you add more data variations so we can see how and when the error kicks in. Does it only happen when the plan is the same?

Comment: I added in the isAAA method. It simply checks Settings to see who the client is. And yes this *only* happens when the Plan is the same (in the examples above, Plan A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes I made that resolved: changed from Start to End Date in the OrderBy.
Also changed it to AsNoTracking.

After testing, the only thing that actually makes a difference is the AsNoTracking() method.

Perhaps someone could explain why this works??

```
else
            {

                var someVariable = DbContext.DbSet<>.AsNoTracking().Where(
                m =>
                    m.Some_ID == CurrentlyEditingSomeID
                ).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.End_Date); 

                return someVariable;
            }
```